# Excluding other parent taxonomy terms when one is selected in "Filter criteria"

Tags: views, 9

I have a table in a content views with a list of four content fields: *City 1*, *City 2*, *City 3*, and *Tourist*.

Because the cities were all taxonomy references in this particular content type, I created a relationship for the Cities vocabulary, a 'Term Parents' contextual filter, and a relationship between the term parents relationship and my Cities vocabulary relationship.

Now, in 'Filter criteria,' I selected Taxonomy term and set a relationship to Parent. I created an exposed filter and I can also select the specific parent terms I want (excluding the child terms, because I just need them to show up underneath my parent terms in the view).

What I want to do is exclude City 1 or 2 and its child terms from showing up when I select City 3 (but keep 'Tourist' on all occasions). How would I go about doing that?